# how to post data from title in href

Tags: php, html

I need to read `$number` from a page in `pagination.php`

```
echo "<span class='pagination'><a href='pagination.php' >  ".$number."    </a></span>";
```

Is it possible? How? thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can solve it by using get:

```
echo "<span class='pagination'><a href='pagination.php?number=". $number ."' >  ". $number ."    </a></span>";
```

In this way, in pagination.php you will be able to retrieve it by reading

```
$_GET['number']
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to append the number as a parameter to the url:

```
echo '<span class="pagination">'
   . '<a href="pagination.php?number=' . urlencode($number) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($number) . '</a>'
   . '</span>';
```

On the pagination.php you will have the number as `$_GET['number']` variable. To avoid Cross-Site-Scripting issues you should encode the number whenever you insert it into the page source (this page and pagination.php). Even better would be to restrict the `$number` to an integer (if it only allows integer values) before inserting it into the page source e.g. with:

```
$number = (int)$number;
```

This way you could insert it safely like this:

```
echo '<span class="pagination">'
   . '<a href="pagination.php?number=' .$number . '">' . $number . '</a>'
   . '</span>';
```

Hope this helps.